# Ember CLI Simple Auth - Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I've got two Ember 1.11 project that is using Simple-Auth via Ember cli simple auth. The simpler of the two (the basic hello world app) works just fine...in fact it works great (simple auth is pretty awesome). However, the other one (a recently upgraded app) has some sort of initialization error.

My error is:

```
Error while processing route: receiving.index Cannot read property 'on' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

And it breaks in ApplicationRouteMixin in the beforeModel function on this line:

```
_this.get(Configuration.sessionPropertyName).on(event, function(error) {
    Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, event);
    var target = routeEntryComplete ? _this : transition;
    target.send.apply(target, arguments);
});
```

The Configuration.sessionPropertyName is "session" and it obviously can't find it. I haven't been able to recreate it outside of this one project, so any help is appreciated.

Sam

Comment: Did you update Simple Auth?

Comment: I've tried with the 0.7.3 and master branch. The error still exists in both.

Comment: What version have you been using previously?

Comment: I've just started incorporating simple-auth, so it's my first version.

Comment: Could you create a gist with your entire file? http://gist.github.com

Comment: @zeppelin give me your github account and I'll make you a collaborator. :-)

Comment: The same as here :) https://github.com/zeppelin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74263/discussion-between-sam-and-zeppelin).

Comment: Will do tomorrow, had to leave the office today!

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out what's the problem, since in my app `container.lookup('route:main').get('session')` works fine after these lines: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/packages/ember-simple-auth/lib/simple-auth/setup.js#L86-L88

Comment: In fact, I can't inject *anything* into `route:application`! Super-strange.

Comment: Spent a couple hours trying to figure out, will resume tomorrow...

Comment: @zeppelin oh that's crazy, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue originated from the fact that one of the dependencies ([ember-modals](https://github.com/sir-dunxalot/ember-modals)) incorrectly instantiated the `route:application` singleton during the initialization process, preventing further injections. `ember-simple-auth` normally injects it's `session` service into `route:application`, but the attempt was silently failing. This behavior [has been fixed](https://github.com/sir-dunxalot/ember-modals/commit/3fb006fd84a13d44db309e82bb52a91599f858f4) in `ember-modals` since `0.3.0`, so upgrading should solve the problem.

Comment: You were great help! Thank you so much for helping